# mmap fails sometimes

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a code from Secure Programming Cookbook for C and C++ by John Viega. The following code snippet opens an executable:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[  ]){ 
        unsigned long entry;
        unsigned char *buf;
        struct stat   sb; 
        int           fd;

        if (stat(argv[1], &sb)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Stat failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 2;
        }
        if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_EXCL)) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Open failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return 3;
        }
        buf = mmap(0, sb.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
        if ((int)buf < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Open failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                close(fd);
                return 4;
        }
}
```

I compiled the above code with gcc 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 x86_64 (`pr`). I have created a copy from the executable (`pr2`).
I do not understand why is the following call sometimes succesful, sometimes not (getting `Open failed: Success`, returning `4`):

```
./pr pr2
```

Comment: Read the manpage of `mmap`. Do not cast the result of `mmap` and compare directly with `MAP_FAILED`.

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile the compiler raises a warning about the unused parameter: `argc`.   Also, never access any argv[] offset beyond argv[0] without first checking argc to assure the command line parameter actually exists.  otherwise the code will be accessing a NULL pointer or worse.  the variable `entry` is unused, line 25 contains cast of pointer to integer of different size

Comment: when indenting code, never use tabs.  Because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.   Suggest using 4 spaces as that allows many indent levels across the page and is visible even with variable width fonts

Comment: Strongly suggest to always enable all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't cast `buf` to an `int`. That's a nonsensical operation. The pointer could easily be in a range that exceeds `INT_MAX`, causing the casted integer to be some negative value that has no real meaning.

Instead, check if the return value of `mmap` was `MAP_FAILED` (which is `(void*)-1`):

```
    buf = mmap(0, sb.st_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(fd);
            return 4;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking the return value of `mmap` correctly.  You need to check specifically for `MAP_FAILED`:

```
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED) {
        // note the change in error message
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return 4;
    }
```

Also, change your error message so that you know that `mmap` failed and not `open`.

Answer (score 3):

You're testing for failure incorrectly:

```
if ((int)buf < 0)
```

As can be seen on [`man mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap), you need to do this:

```
if (buf == MAP_FAILED)
```

Or this:

```
if (buf == (void*)-1)
```

Otherwise you are casting a valid pointer to an int which happens to be negative, but not -1, and you treat it as an error when it is not.